# google apps scriptでSpreadsheetにbuttonを作る方法

Tags: html

google apps scriptを使って、対象Spreadsheetのsheetの指定cellにbuttonのようなユーザインタフェースをつくりたいが、そのやり方について教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

**cell内にbuttonを作成することはできません。**

[stackoverflow](http://There%20seems%20to%20be%20no%20way%20to%20place%20buttons%20(drawings,%20images)%20within%20cells%20in%20a%20way%20that%20would%20allow%20them%20to%20be%20linked%20to%20Apps%20Script%20functions.)

> There seems to be no way to place buttons (drawings, images) within cells in a way that would allow them to be linked to Apps Script functions.